# test if array is multidimensional

Tags: javascript, arrays

How would I test to see if a variable includes an multidimensional array?   For example:

```
var obj = [1, 2];
```

vs

```
var obj = [[1], [2]];
```

I have used  Array.isArray(obj) to test whether is an array, but I can't figure out how to test the number of arrays.

Comment: That's easy, open the console and the second one will generate a syntax error !

Comment: `if( Object.prototype.toString.call( someVar ) === '[object Array]' ) {
    alert( 'Array!' );
}`

Comment: A variable can always only contain a single value, hence it can only contain a single array. Maybe you used the wrong words to describe the problem. If so, please provide more context.

Comment: Do u mean multidimensional arrays?

Comment: Do you mean `var ratings = [[1], [2]]`? If so, you'd have to then check if each value is an array as well as checking if `ratings` is an array.

Comment: yes multidimensional array.  I'm a noob to javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you meant

```
var ratings = [[1], [2]];
```

as `var ratings = [1], [2];` is a syntax error,  you could do

```
ratings.filter(Array.isArray).length
```

to get the number of arrays inside the wrapping array (2)

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZSNm/)

Comment: cool, worked perfectly.  Thanks for reading between the error filled lines.